# Naming awk outputs according to directory name

Tags: bash, awk

I have an awk script I need to run on every file in several directories. If the file paths are:

```
/home/user/folder1/run1/sample1/scans
/home/user/folder2/run1/sample1/scans
```

I only need to run the awk script on the `scans` folder within `run1` for each `folder#`. So the only differentiating naming convention for the output is in the `folder#`. How can I have the awk script name the output depending on which `folder#` directory I am in?

eg `folder1.txt`, then `folder2.txt`, etc?

I'm really new with awk and I'm ok with feeding it a bunch of .txt inputs within a single folder, but not pointing it to entire batches of folders.

Reorganizing the folder structure is not an option, as it is a shared file system in a collaboration.

Comment: I think you'd want to use `find` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this awk command:

```
s='/home/user/folder1/run1/sample1/scans'
awk -F '/' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="run1") print $(i-1);}' <<< "$s"
folder1
```

Using `find` and `awk` together:

```
find /home/user*/run1/*/scans -type d -exec \
     awk -F '/' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="run1") print $(i-1);}' <<< '{}' \;
```

Comment: I have always disliked the convention of escaping the semicolon. You quoted everything else in your command, save the newline. Why not quote the semicolon?

Comment: Backslash after exec is to avoid horizontal scrolling and one before semi colon is conventional syntax and it saves one keystroke from `';'` :-)

Comment: Yeah, but you also couldve wrote `-F/` and you didnt